# Why does Yang-cha wear a face mask?

Tags: arthdal-chronicles

In *Arthdal Chronicles*, one of Tagon's Daeken soldiers, Yang-cha, since the very start of the series, constantly wears a black face mask that covers their mouth and nose, which I would imagine might render it uncomfortable to breathe.

[image: Yang-cha in his face mask]

None of the other soldiers have anything remotely similar. This is a setting without much technology, so it's certainly not a gas mask or anything similar. Is it to conceal some facial injury? To make them more intimidating? As a mouth guard?

Comment: I've edited in an image just so it's clearer what you are asking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't seen the show and I can't find a transcript for it online anywhere at the moment but apparently in episode 2 (not sure of which season, 1 or 2) it is said that Yang-cha wears the face mask because he is being punished and is not allowed to speak. Why he is being punished is not said.

> Mu Kwang (Hwang Hee) 's remarks that "I am punished not to speak" is further amplified by the mystery surrounding Yang Cha, while Yang Cha is trying to use the new bronze "bronze chute" Ya (Kim Ji Won), and Eun-seom (Song Jung Gi) to fight against the powerful force of the tension of the pole has heightened.
>
> <sub>[SM Entertainment, tvN 'Arthdal ​​Chronicles' Yang Cha Role Ki Do Hun, Audience Curiosity](https://www.smentertainment.com/PressCenter/Details/3109)</sub>

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arthdal_Chronicles) also states the same thing about the character:

> Ki Do-hoon as Yang-cha
> A Daekan warrior who is adept at using bronze weapons. He always wears a mask over his mouth, as he is serving a punishment of silence for something that happened in the past. Ta-gon gave young Yang-cha a secret order in the past. Ta-gon also reveals to Yang-cha his true feelings. Within the Daekan troops, he is reputed to be comparable to Mu-baek, seen as the best Warrior of the next generation.

It is worth noting that the mask itself is real as the actor wears it so whilst it would make breathing harder it mustn't hinder it that much. You can see this on his [Instagram](https://www.instagram.com/p/BzS_Q1XAHCR/?utm_source=ig_embed) where he shared a video of him in makeup having the mask put on.

Answer (score 1):

In the second season, *The Sword of Aramun*, it is revealed that Yang-cha wears the mask because he was once one of the Children of Shahati, children raised to be assassins who generally owe their loyalty to the Hae clan. As part of the training and conditioning that these children are subject to, they consume substances (or perhaps get tattoos?) that turn their tongues black, something that would naturally be revealed if Yang-cha did not constantly cover his mouth. In the second season, when Tagon tells him that he can remove the mask, he notes that the black color must have faded almost entirely.

Still, particularly with the other element of not being allowed to speak, there also might be an element of punishment there for having been a Child of Shahati, perhaps even one of the ones that tried to kill Tagon. It is also true that Tagon calls it a punishment when he says that Yang-cha can remove his mask and start speaking once more.